# Validation form error check button does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making verification form.

When I wrote all the code first the checkbox showed but when I complete the code the check button did not work.

Please check my code and help me to run it.

It runs if I don't add validation; when I add validation the check button disappears

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const Username = document.getElementById('Username');
const Email = document.getElementById('Email');
const Mobilenummber = document.getElementById('Mobile nummber');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const Confirmpassword = document.getElementById('Confirm password');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  validate();

})
const isEmail = (Emailval) => {
  var atsymbol = Emailval.indexof('@');
  if (atsymbol < 1) return false;
  var dot = Emailval.lastindexof('.');
  if (dot <= atsymbol + 2) return false;
  if (dot === Emailval.length - 1) return false;
  return true;
}


const validate = () => {
  const Usernameval = Username.value.trim();
  const Emailval = Email.value.trim();
  const Mobilenummberval = Mobilenummber.value.trim();
  const passwordval = password.value.trim();
  const Confirmpasswordval = Confirmpassword.value.trim();

  if (Usernameval === "") {
    setErrorMsg(Username, 'username cannot be blank');

  } else if (Usernameval.length <= 2) {
    setErrorMsg(Username, 'username must have 3 cheacter');
  } else {
    setSuccessMsg(Username);
  }

  if (Emailval === "") {
    setErrorMsg(Email, 'Email cannot be blank');

  } else if (!isEmail(Emailval)) {
    setErrorMsg(Emailval, ' type your email correctly');
  } else {
    setSuccessMsg(Email);
  }

  function setErrorMsg(input, errormsgs) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.queryselector('small');
    formControl.className = "form-control error small";
    small.innerText = errormsgs;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-PgQMlq+nqFLV4ylk1gwUOgm6CtIIXkKwaIHp/PAIWHzig/lKZSEGKEysh0TCVbHJXCLN7WetD8TFecIky75ZfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Registration form</h2>
    <div>
      <form class="form" id="form">
        <div class="form-control">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your full name" autocomplete="off">
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
          <small>Error Msg</small>
        </div>
        <div>
          <form class="form" id="form">
            <div class="form-control">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="Enter your Email" autocomplete="off">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
              <small>Error Msg</small>
            </div>
            <div>
              <form class="form" id="form">
                <div class="form-control">
                  <label>Mobilenumber</label>
                  <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your Mobile num" autocomplete="off">
                  <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                  <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                  <small>Error Msg</small>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <form class="form" id="form">
                    <div class="form-control">
                      <label>password</label>
                      <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" autocomplete="off">
                      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                      <small>Error Msg</small>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <form class="form" id="form">
                        <div class="form-control">
                          <label>Confirmpassword</label>
                          <input type="text" id="Confirm password" placeholder="Enter your password again" autocomplete="off">
                          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                          <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                          <small>Error Msg</small>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn" name="">


                      </form>

                    </div>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: You really need to go read up on some basics. You can not nest forms into each other, that is invalid HTML. You are using the same ID multiple times, which is also not allowed.

Comment: You have very clear errors. Fix those first. For example: `const username = document.getElementById('username').value.trim()`

Comment: The `id` of mobile number input field is `phone`. So correct that in your JS code.

Comment: And the ID of your phone number input field is `id="phone"`, yet you are doing `const Mobilenummber = document.getElementById('Mobile nummber');` in your script. (And `Mobile nummber` would not even be a valid ID, IDs can't contain spaces.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the errors fixed.

Please study what I changed

Spelling and CASE is important in JavaScript

Be consistent. Use camelCase wisely and consistently

It is also recommended to be DRY - so I have ONE message function for you

Actually the isEmail can be removed since the HTML5 validation will do it for it.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirmPassword');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  if (!validate()) event.preventDefault();
})

const setMsg = (input, errormsg) => {
  const formControl = input.closest(".form-control");
  formControl.querySelector(".fas").classList.toggle("fa-check-circle", !errormsg)
  formControl.querySelector(".fas").classList.toggle("fa-exclamation-circle", errormsg)
  formControl.querySelector('small').textContent = errormsg ? errormsg : "OK";
  formControl.querySelector('.msg').style.display = "inline";
};

const isEmail = (Emailval) => {
  var atsymbol = Emailval.indexOf('@');
  if (atsymbol < 1) return false;
  var dot = Emailval.lastIndexOf('.');
  if (dot <= atsymbol + 2) return false;
  if (dot === Emailval.length - 1) return false;
  return true;
}

const validate = () => {
  const usernameVal = username.value.trim();
  const emailVal = email.value.trim();
  const phoneVal = phone.value.trim();
  const passwordval = password.value.trim();
  const confirmPasswordVal = confirmPassword.value.trim();

  if (usernameVal === "") {
    setMsg(username, 'username cannot be blank');
    return false
  } else if (usernameVal.length <= 2) {
    setMsg(username, 'username must have 3 cheacter');
    return false
  } else {
    setMsg(username);
  }

  if (emailVal === "") {
    setMsg(email, 'Email cannot be blank');
    return false
  } else if (!isEmail(emailVal)) {
    setMsg(email, ' type your email correctly');
    return false
  } else {
    setMsg(email);
  }
}
```

```css
.msg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-PgQMlq+nqFLV4ylk1gwUOgm6CtIIXkKwaIHp/PAIWHzig/lKZSEGKEysh0TCVbHJXCLN7WetD8TFecIky75ZfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Registration form</h2>
    <form class="form" id="form">
      <div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your full name" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="msg"><i class="fas"></i> <small></small></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="msg"><i class="fas"></i> <small></small></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label>Mobilenumber</label>
          <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your Mobile num" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="msg"><i class="fas"></i> <small></small></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label>password</label>
          <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="msg"><i class="fas"></i> <small></small></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label>Confirmpassword</label>
          <input type="text" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Enter your password again" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="msg"><i class="fas"></i> <small></small></span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn" name="">

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```